# Databricks does not display the grid search info with verbose mode when n_jobs > 1

Tags: databricks, grid-search, gridsearchcv, databricks-ml

When I run the machine learning algorithm using Grid Search with verbose as 10 and n_jobs as -1, the info for each model is not getting displayed in databricks. If I use n_jobs as 1, then each param grid combination output is getting displayed. Any values greater than 1 results in no info on the notebook rather it just displays the completed message without any verbose info of each model fit.

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Can you share the code that you are running?